# jQuery confirm and then post with ajaxForm

Tags: jquery, confirm

The following jQuery code executes the `ajaxForm` function even if I press the `Cancel` button. In addition, the `success` part doesn't update the `content`, either. Can anybody tell me what's wrong with it? Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".myForm").click(function (e) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
      $(".myForm").ajaxForm ({
        success: function(returnData) {
          $('#content').html(returnData);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The click event should be set on a button element, and you should use `.ajaxSubmit()`, rather than `.ajaxForm()`.

Either the button should not be a submit button (that is, `<input type="submit">` or `<button type="submit">`) or else you need to call `e.preventDefault()`.

Try something like this:

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" />
    <button type="submit" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
<form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#submitButton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        $("#myForm").ajaxSubmit({
            success: function(returnData) {
                $('#content').html(returnData);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: That works. Thanks a lot. However, if the form contains files and images for uploading, would `ajaxSubmit` work?

Comment: Well, there is a problem. The form won't check the "required" input fields and submit even if some fields are left blank. Any suggestions?

Comment: The [FAQ Page](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#faq) for the jQuery Form Plugin says it supports file uploads.

Comment: As for checking required fields, you can add logic after the call to `e.preventDefault()` if you need.